# Is it possible to write html code using javascript (and save it)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making some html files for fun, and i am trying to make a social-media thing, and the only idea that came me was to write html using javascript and the only thing i found that work is `document.write()` but it does not save in the html file. Is it atleast possible? If it is.. how can you do it? (or with anything else)

EDIT : i do not mean to make another file, i want to modify the one i run the javascript (or anything else) script that will SAVE the source code.

EDIT 2 : please ignore this question. thanks

Comment: No. You will need AJAX for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Comment: You can make a chrome extension which take permission and store the file on disk, check this https://codemirror.net/  all you need is implement it in chrome web extension.

Comment: @Aankhen i do not want to generate a file, i want to replace the existing one

Comment: Are you talking about using JavaScript _on the client_ to change the HTML file _on the server_? If not, and if you want to change a file _on the client_, it’s up to the user what they save it as. You don’t have any control over the filename, hence the duplicate.

Comment: oh.. well then nevermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to have access to clients computer using JavaScript is NodeJS. With regular browser JavaScript, you cannot save files on the client's computer. If you want to stay with browser `document.write` or `DOMElement.innerHTML = <div></div>` are your options.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible.
The basic principle is that you can give a unique id for each HTML element (e.g. ,); and then using document.getElementById command to get the element and then set the innerHTML or textContent attribute to the string that you want.

Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="pp">
   </div>
   <div id="qq">
   </div>

   <button onclick="changeText()">Update the text</div>
   <script>
      function changeText()
      {
          var div1=document.getElementById("pp");
          var div2=document.getElementById("qq");
          div1.innerHTML="Hello";
          div2.textContent="World";
      } 
   </script>
```

However, there are so many frameworks can make your life easier.

Comment: yeah but it does not save the text in the html. i meant to MODIFY the html and add text, not just for one instance.

Comment: As Ertan said that, "With regular browser JavaScript, you cannot save files on the client's computer.", by the way, would you tell us what do you want to do? Otherwise, we cannot help you.

Comment: as i said in the post, i wanted to make a social media thing, and the only idea that came me was to make a prompt window to enter the message you wanted to share, and a script that would add the text to the html. maybe there are other alternatives but this is the one that came into my head

Comment: do you want to build it by yourself? Or using an open source solution?

Comment: myself because i do it on a html file

Comment: It cannot be implemented by HTML and javascript only.
You need an application server.
You need to write a server-side program.